# Finding the worst case running time of this piece of code?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I am working with this code:

```
function strange (list a[0..n-1] of integers such that abs(a[i]) ≤ n for every 0 ≤ i ≤ n - 1, list b[0..2n] of zeroes)

for i ← 0 to n - 1 do
       a[i] ← a[i] + n
for i ← 0 to n - 1 do
       for j ← 0 to abs(a[i] - 1) do 
              b[j] ← b[j] + 1
return b
```

I am trying to figure out the worst running time for the code above and so far I'm guessing that the first for loop will run n times, but not sure how to prove this. For the second and third for loop, I'm unsure how to approach this.
If possible, could someone help me solve this?

Comment: How large can abs(a[i] - 1) be?

Answer (score 0):

$O(n)$ for the first section and $O(n^2)$ for the second, so $O(n^2)$ overall.